# Add filtering system to MapBox Map

Tags: javascript, html, css, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

We have made a store locator map using the MapBox js code, based on their documentation that we've been able to find, but we are having some trouble implementing a dropdown filtering systems into the map, that filters based on the State.

We've tried using these documentations to produce something similar, but can't seem to get it to work.

- https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/
- https://labs.mapbox.com/education/impact-tools/finder-with-filters/

Is there a way that we can add a dropdown filtering system to the current map that we have made?

Here is a test link for our initial store locator map: https://test.versacreativedev.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/FidelityCareers-MAPBOX_Map.html

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at the Finder Impact Tool, which implements filtering. You may be able to use this directly, or borrow ideas for your existing implementation.

https://labs.mapbox.com/education/impact-tools/finder-with-filters/